# Unable to scp and rsync through root user

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have ubuntu machine 16.04 which is running in aws ec2, we are able to ssh,scp and rsync through the default user ( ubuntu ) from my local windows machine . Could you please anyone suggest me on this how to do those through root user. I have added that machine to seccurity group to allow from anywhere and added private key to the server which is generated from my windows machine

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this that may help with your analysis.

1. The root user on machine A is not the root user on machine B. 'root' is universally unique to its machine.
2. SSHD is often configured to disable root logins. So if you want to login as root@machineB you must ensure that root login is enabled on machine B.